# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'document' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, csv

I have a function, which takes a CSV and processes it. I am trying to count the rows in the CSV file before running through it to ensure I get to the end.

```
def parse_campaigns_cutsheet(country_code, input_file, DB, DB_hist, zip_id):

    filecontent = urllib2.urlopen(input_file)
    count = 0

    csvFile = csv.DictReader(filecontent)
    rowage = len(list(csvFile))

    for row in csvFile:
        count += 1

        if 'MM' not in row['Tier']:
            continue

        if RB_COUNTRIES_new[country_code]['cut_sheet_country'] != row['Country']:
            continue

        document = DB.find_one({'rb_account_id': RB_COUNTRIES_new[country_code]['rb_account_id']})

        if document is None:
            continue

        DB.save(document)

report_work(document, DB, DB_hist)
```

I keep getting the following error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'document' referenced before assignment`. If i remove the `rowage = len(list(csvFile))` line it works fine?

Comment: `csvFile` is an generator, by `list(csvFile)`, you exhausted the generator. Hence the for loop won't be entered if the line `rowage = len(list(csvFile))` is present. If the for loop is not entered, `document` is not defined. Hence your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `DictReader` is a generator.

When you call `list` on `DictReader`, it will `yield` all the values into the list, and won't be iterable any more.

That why when your for-loop tries to iterate over it, it never does, and the `document` will never be assigned.

If you want to accomplish what you're trying to do, you can keep a reference to the list and then iterate over the **list**:

```
...
csvFile = csv.DictReader(filecontent)
filecontent_list = list(csvFile)
rowage = len(filecontent_list)

for row in filecontent_list:
...
```

**Keep in mind** - this is mean that all your data will be saved in memory!
When iterating over the generator without forcing it to be a list, only one iterating are being saved in the memory each time.

Comment: *"This happens because the `DictReader` is a generator."* And because generators are one-shot iterables--you can only iterate over their data once and only once, next time you iterate over them you get `StopIteration` exception. Some iterables are their own iterators, one iteration over all their data exhausts them. *"When you call list on `DictReader`, it will yield all the values into the list, and won't be iterable anymore."*  `DictReader` is still considered to be an iterable after iterating over its data, but an exhausted iterable after iteration.